# How to pass an Array of selected check boxes values concatenated with text boxes values to an MVC controller via jquery and Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC .I've got a project using ASP.NET using the MVC5 framework.I have a view called addContract which contain two dropdownList one of a service provider the second is for services. I also have a two datepickers begin and end date , a text box for the number of contract and finally a table that contains a list of article and i will choose which article i want in the contract and the price.Every thing is good for the moment i have implement a function which will add the value of selected check box and the value of the text box for the price and concatinate them in an array and send it to the controller via ajax and jquery. the problem is when i go to controller i got Null in the variable for the array. but all the other values for the services and date are fine.

Please help me and what is the best way to do that !!!

and this is my view code just the code of the table in which i find the problem :

```
         <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="tab">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Choose</td>
                                <td>Reference</td>
                                <td>Article Name</td>
                                <td>Price</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var ar in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="@ar.reference" ID="chk" class="check"></td>

                                    <td>@ar.reference</td>
                                    <td>@ar.Name</td>


                                 <td> <input type="text" id="txt" name="@ar.reference" placeholder="TND" ></td>

                                </tr>
                            }

                        </tbody>
                    </table>



this is the jquery script :

    //***testing if a checkbox is selected and add the selected row in an array***//
    //the table that will store selected items
    var Num_Contrat = "";
    var Date_Deb = "";
    var Date_Fin = "";
    var Price = "";
    var Service_Provider_List = "";
    var Service_List = "";
    var selected = [];

    //**(1)   -im gonna find the table body and checkbox
    $('table#tab tbody').on('change', '.check', function () {


            var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");

            if (ischecked) {

                selected.push($(this).val() + "," + $(this).closest('tr').find("#txt").val());







            } else {
                if ((index = selected.indexOf($(this).val() + "," + $(this).closest('tr').find("#txt").val())) !== -1) {
                    selected.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }

            // (4) -and finnally i m gonna  Remove duplicate elements from selected array
            selected = $.unique(selected);
            alert(selected);

        });

        //Validation
        $("#Service_Provider_List").keyup(function () {
            var vall = $(this).val();
            if (vall == "") {
                $("#dpl1error").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' style='color:red;'></span>");
                Service_Provider_List = "";
            }
            else {
                $("#dpl1error").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='color:green;'></span>");
                Service_Provider_List = vall;
            }
        });
        $("#Service_List").keyup(function () {
            var vall = $(this).val();
            if (vall == "") {
                $("#dpl2error").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' style='color:red;'></span>");
                Service_List = "";
            }
            else {
                $("#dpl2error").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='color:green;'></span>");
                Service_List = vall;
            }
        });
        $("#Date_Deb").keyup(function () {
            var vall = $(this).val();
            if (vall == "") {
                $("#dpkerror").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' style='color:red;'></span>");
                Date_Deb = "";
            }
            else {
                $("#dpkerror").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='color:green;'></span>");
                Date_Deb = vall;
            }
        });
        $("#Date_Fin").keyup(function () {
            var vall = $(this).val();
            if (vall == "") {
                $("#dpk2error").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' style='color:red;'></span>");
                Date_Fin = "";
            }
            else {
                $("#dpk2error").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='color:green;'></span>");
                Date_Fin = vall;
            }
        });
        $("#Num_Contrat").keyup(function () {
            var vall = $(this).val();
            if (vall == "") {
                $("#inpnumerror").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' style='color:red;'></span>");
                Num_Contrat = "";
            }
            else {
                $("#inpnumerror").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='color:green;'></span>");
                Num_Contrat = vall;
            }
        });




        $("#btnsub").click(function () {
            var prices = [];
            $('input:checked').each(function () {

                prices.push($(this).attr("value"));
            });
            var test = JSON.stringify(selected);


            if (Service_Provider_List == "" || Service_List == "" || Date_Deb == "" || Date_Fin == "" || Num_Contrat == "") {
                $("#btnerror").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' style='color:red;'> Please enter the missing fields ! </span>");
            }
            else {

            $("#btnerror").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='color:green;'> You successfully added a contract</span>");

            //ajax call


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("addcontract")',
                data: '{"Num_Contrat":' + JSON.stringify(Num_Contrat) + '"Date_Deb":' + JSON.stringify(Date_Deb) + '"Date_Fin":' + JSON.stringify(Date_Fin) + '"Service_Provider_List":' + JSON.stringify(Service_Provider_List) + '"Service_List":' + JSON.stringify(Service_List) + '"selected":' + test + '}',
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                traditional: true,


                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }

            });



            }

        });
```

controller :

```
 //Manage Contract
    // **Add Contract
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addcontract(string Num_Contrat,string Date_Deb,string Date_Fin,string Service_Provider_List,
        string Service_List,IEnumerable<string> selected)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE=XE;USER ID=gbon;password=gbon";
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand();
            OracleCommand com1 = new OracleCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com1.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CONTRACT VALUES('" + Num_Contrat + "','" + Date_Deb + "','" + Date_Fin + "','" + Service_Provider_List + "','" + Service_List + "')";
         //   com1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ARTICLE_CONTRACT VALUES('" + selected + "')";
            return Json(new { add="done"});
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Comment: 80% of this code is irrelevant to the question and it unlikely anyone will wade through it all (refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)`

Comment: To generate your data your need `data: JSON.stringify({ Num_Contrat: someValue, Date_Deb: someValue, selected: someArray });` (and remove `traditional: true,` and do not use `async: false,`)

Comment: thanks @StephenMuecke, i finally did it :D !